# What is the range of values after applying Standardization?

Tags: means, standard-deviation

I was working on a ML model, and after applying Feature Scaling (Standardization), I observed some of the scaled value is lesser than -3 and some are greater than +3.

```
In school days I learn that after Standardization, the range of value is [-3, +3].
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

What is the range of values after applying **Standardization** ?